# Induction $(1+\frac{1}{x^n})(1+\frac{1}{y^n}) \geq (1+2^n)^2$

Tags: inequality

How to prove this inequality using Induction (or any simpler method):
Let (x,y) be real positive numbers, so that x+y=1; and n an integer:

Prove this:
$\begin{align}(1+\frac{1}{x^n})(1+\frac{1}{y^n}) \geq (1+2^n)^2\end{align}$

Comment: There must be some further restriction on $x$ and $y$. For example for $x = y = 1$, the inequality doesn't hold (for $n > 0$).

Comment: I don't think you stated it quite correctly.  That inequality would be violated by $x=y=2$ and $n=1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so sorry, I corrected it ..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan so sorry, it's corrected now ..

Answer (score 2):

Replace $ y$ with $1-x$.

**Hint:** Show that $ \frac{1}{4} \geq x(1-x)$.

**Hint:** Show that $\frac{1}{x^n} \times \frac{1}{(1-x)^n} \geq 2^{2n} $.

**Hint:** Show that $ \frac{ 1}{x^n} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^n} \geq 2 \times 2^n$ using the [technique AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-am-gm/).

Expand and compare.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof is Jensen inequality. Firstly take a logarithm from both side:
$$
\log(1+\frac{1}{x^n})+\log(1+\frac{1}{y^n}) \geq 2\log(1+2^n)
$$
Note that $f(x)=\log(1+\frac{1}{x^n})$ is a convex function for positive $x$, therefore:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log(1+\frac{1}{x^n})+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+\frac{1}{y^n})\geq \log(1+\frac{1}{(\frac{x+y}{2})^n})=\log(1+2^n).
$$
This proves your result.